# Is there a way, from within an AWS Lambda function, to get the log stream name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to get the name of a Lambda’s log stream, as displayed in the “monitor” tab of the Lambda console, from within the function itself? I have millions of AWS Lambda functions running with Python, and I'd like to output each log stream’s name to our result file in order to find the logs more easily.

The log stream name looks like this:

```
YYYY/MM/DD/[$latest]45ea5df5ec5a4f15e1f5af8a5f12e8
```

Comment: you can get the name of the logstream and the name of the loggroup from the context object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html

Comment: @Korgen you should post it as an awser so I can accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can get the name of the logstream and the name of the loggroup from the context object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html

`context.log_group_name`